# Why does toupper function return an ASCII instead of a char?

Tags: c++, string, char

Take any string (e.g. hello world). The code below will supposingly cout the all-caps version of "hello world", instead I get this : ( "72 69 76 76 79 32 87 79 82 76 68" )

```
char a[256];
cin.getline(a, 256);

for(int i = 0; i < strlen(a); i++){
    cout << toupper(a[i]) << " "; 
}
```

However, if I remove toupper I get the normal string, why does this happen with toupper?

Comment: If you look at the documentation for that function, you'll see it returns `int`.  It always has.  This is how those functions work.  Are you asking why that is?  Or are you just asking how to make it output as a `char`?

Comment: "_Like all other functions from `<cctype>`, the behavior of `std::toupper` is undefined if the argument's value is neither representable as unsigned char nor equal to `EOF`. To use these functions safely with plain `char`s (or `signed char`s), **the argument should first be converted to unsigned char**_"

Comment: `cout << static_cast<char>(toupper(static_cast<unsigned char>(a[i]))) << " ";`